# How do I install GIMP's "save for web" plugin on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gimp

After updating Ubuntu to 20.04, some programs are a little broken.
I had to completely re-install gimp in order to update the GEGL libraries.

After reinstalling GIMP, the "save for web" script doesn't show in the menus.

I'd like to reinstall it.

I found the git repo for it. However, the install instructions don't seem to work.
The instructions direct the user to use 'configure'. However, there is no configure script.

How can the 'save for web' plugin be installed?

Comment: "Save for web" is a bit outdated. 1) AFAIK it doesn't support Webp, that could be a useful target format and 2) in 2.10 the JPEG export dialog lets you to check in real-time the file size and the image degradation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install single package [with needed plugin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gimp-plugin-registry/filelist):

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe

sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```